# \graphicspath & Dropbox

Tags: includegraphics, paths

Hmmm... I have an issue that may or may not be a problem with a Dropbox situation?  I have my .tex file in a folder on my Mac called 'Staff Handbook'.  Inside this folder is another folder called 'Staff Manual Images - Resources'.  On my first run of compiling this file this has worked fine.  I have opened this file at in a different WiFi area and the image files are not found (but they are there).

I am wondering... the 'Staff Handbook' folder is in a Dropbox folder that is a 'smart folder' on my Mac.  Is it possible that this is causing the images to not be found?

If so, is there a way that I can use the \graphicspath function? If so, how do I treat the white spaces?

My path is:

Mackintosh HD/Users/simonbradley/Dropbox/Bradleys Coffee - Group/Staff Handbook/Staff Manual Images - Resources/

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: as you have shown no code not really possible to offer any help. Note that paths in tex are relative to the working directory of the tex process not relative to the main document file, so it is usually necessary to make these the same so `cd` to `/Users/simonbradley/Dropbox/Bradleys Coffee - Group/Staff Handbook/` then `pdflatex file.tex` not `pdflatex /Users/simonbradley/Dropbox/Bradleys Coffee - Group/Staff Handbook//file.tex` If your tex installation isn't old spaces should work without issues.

Comment: About the white spaces, it's generally best to avoid them. I.e. shorten your directory and filenames. // Wrt dropbox can you try creating and accessing a link? // Remote data access typically involves synchronization, which sometimes means "just wait". So changing the WiFi area may have been a root cause OR just incidentally. // Because Apple is a different species, also when it comes to low level access, this part of your question might be better suited for a Mac OS forum.

Comment: How is it best to add my code here?  If I copy & paste it ends up as one long sentence?

Many Thanks

Comment: EDIT - very strange... I created an account on 'Overleaf' and copied the entire code over... compiled just fine?